# checking if a string variable has data in it, which one is better !empty() or '!'

Tags: php

it occured to me that some people prefer to use `!empty($val)` over `!$val` to check a strings existance. what are the advantages of using `!empty()` over `!` if any? 
lets assume string can be:

1. null
2. ""
3. "false"
4. "1"
5. "0"

all of the above give the same result in both methods. is there any other case that would cause problems using one instead of the other?

Comment: i use always the function isset : -> !isset($val)

Comment: a string variable can be set but empty.

Comment: I would use isset() as it can also be applied to unknown variables. Here's a link to a useful article on the subject http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/#axzz2tgJiY6rt

Comment: @OllyRatio `!empty($var)` is equivalent to `isset($var) && $var`.

Comment: `isset()` is not equal to `!empty()` if `$var = ""`, `isset($var)` will return true and `!empty($var)` will return false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `empty($var)` vs. `!$var` a.k.a. `$var == false`

The only difference is that `empty` does not throw an *Undefined variable* notice if the variable does not exist, otherwise they're both identical. Now, if you are sure that the variable *should* exist, use just `!`. If the variable may *legitimately not exist*, use `empty`. If you needlessly use `empty`, you're just needlessly disabling PHP's error reporting mechanism which may help you catch problems with mistyped variables or logic errors.

Also see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).